# Internal sets in a category

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be any category with finite limits, and write $S$ for the category of finite sets, thought of as an essentially algebraic theory.

Do we always recover $\mathcal{C}$ itself when considering Set-models in $\mathcal{C}$? (i.e. finite-limit preserving functors $S^{op}$ to $\mathcal{C}$)?

Comment: In general I think there's only an embedding of $Mod(S, {\cal C})$ into $\cal C$: since $\cal C$ has finite limits, it has finite products, and now $S^{op}$ is the free category with finite products generated by a singleton, so that $Mod(S,{\cal C}) \hookrightarrow [S^{op}, {\cal C}]_\times \cong \cal C$ where the central object is the category of product preserving functors.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Ah so if instead of viewing finite sets as an essentially algebraic theory I view them as a Lawvere theory I do get $\mathcal{C}$ back. Is this definitely true?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely true.

Comment: I am undeleting this question. You have already been informed here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2400878/43208, in strong terms, that deleting a question just after getting an answer is considered rude. I will repeat what was said at Math.SE: don't do this. Ever. If there is some very pressing reason for deletion after an answer has been posted, please explain in a flag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed; with a view towards Fosco's comment, product-preserving functors $S^{op} \to C$ automatically preserve finite limits. This is related to Gabriel-Ulmer duality, but we can argue without that apparatus.

First, I claim it suffices to check this in the case $C = \text{Set}$. This is because the Yoneda embedding $y: C \to \text{Set}^{C^{op}}$ both preserves and reflects (finite) limits, so that $F: S^{op} \to C$ preserves finite limits iff $y \circ F: S^{op} \to \text{Set}^{C^{op}}$ does. But since finite limits in $\text{Set}^{C^{op}}$ are computed pointwise, it suffices to check that for all $c \in \text{Ob}(C)$, the composite

$$S^{op} \stackrel{y F}{\to} \text{Set}^{C^{op}} \stackrel{\text{eval}_c}{\to} \text{Set}$$

preserves finite limits if it preserves finite products; this establishes the claim.

Now to finish, a product-preserving functor $F: S^{op} \to \text{Set}$ is determined up to (unique) isomorphism by the value $X = F(1)$. If $i: S \to \text{Set}$ is the full inclusion, this $F$ is given by $\text{Set}(i-, X)$ (since $\text{Set}(i-, X)$ is after all product-preserving and returns the value $X$ at the argument $1$). But since $i$ preserves finite colimits, the functor

$$Set(i-, X) = (S^{op} \stackrel{i^{op}}{\to} \text{Set}^{op} \stackrel{Set(-, X)}{\to} \text{Set})$$

preserves finite limits.